# Complex built-in function in python

Tags: python-2.7

I am reading data from a file so I have a value say,

```
a = '-1.179297799365114230e+01+-2.024886536109358204e+00j'
```

Then i am using complex() to convert the string into complex number. But it the showing an error.

ValueError: complex() arg is a malformed string

I couldn't understand why. The number does not includes any white spaces.
Kindly suggest some measures to remove this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/complex

`The syntax of complex() is: complex([real[, imag]])`

So just write:

```
a = '-1.179297799365114230e+01+-2.024886536109358204e+00j'
fragments = a.split('+')
real = float(fragments[0]+'+'+fragments[1])
imag = float(fragments[2]+'+'+fragments[3][:-1])
complex(real, imag)
```

This assume that you'll always be given the complex number as a string in scientific notation as in the example. If you're unsure wether or not this is the case, you'll probably want to include checks such as `assert(len(a.split('+')) == 4)`. The float() function automatically converts the strings in scientific notation to floats.